# Array more Efficient than Dictionary

Tags: c#

I had the following method in my code.  My boss asked "why are you using a dictionary", you can just use an array, it's more efficient:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetListOfMonths()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> months = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        months.Add("1", "Jan");
        months.Add("2", "Feb");
        months.Add("3", "Mar");
        months.Add("4", "Apr");
        months.Add("5", "May");
        months.Add("6", "Jun");
        months.Add("7", "Jul");
        months.Add("8", "Aug");
        months.Add("9", "Sep");
        months.Add("10", "Oct");
        months.Add("11", "Nov");
        months.Add("12", "Dec");

        return months;
    }
```

I use this for code reuse..so that I can bind to some month dropdown menus in various parts of our application.

Comment: You can save some time and just use System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames.

Comment: Good question (though likely a duplicate), bad example code, seriously questionable reaction comment from your boss.

Answer (score 19):

An array is certainly more efficient for reasonably dense collections based on an integer index.

On the other hand, an array won't let you use a `string` key as you've got for your dictionary.

Back to the first hand, why do you *want* a string key for your dictionary?

I wouldn't get too hung up on the performance aspect though - write the most readable code. If you're sure that using a string key is more appropriate here, then go ahead with the dictionary. The alternative (if you've been presented with a string) is to parse the integer and index into the array.

It's not really feasible for us to say which will be the best solution here.

Comment: for a dropdownlist.  That's why I want a string key.  But maybe when you bind to the dropdownlist it will just convert that integer to string anyway for the value of the dropdownlist.

Comment: (I wouldn't get too hung up on the performance aspect though - write the most readable code.)  Well that's not so easily said for a .com where performance on a site that receives about 1 million hits a month relies on every little ounce of efficiency gains you can give it.

Comment: @coffeeaddict - The fact that you're creating a new dictionary each time you call this method rather than using a single static instance will likely do more to hurt your performance than the choice between an array and a dictionary; you're looking at a bunch of allocations and 12 method calls here. In any case (a) a million hits a month isn't very much really, and (b) if you haven't profiled the application then you're undoubtedly optimising the wrong place anyway.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: When people say "don't get hung up on the performance aspect" they typically mean that there's little performance difference between the options and that you shouldn't worry about it until you can demonstrate that the code in question is a bottleneck using a profiler. Before that, just use common sense and write readable code.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: A million hits per month is actually very small. That's less than one hit per second. If that's causing you performance problems, you've got *much* bigger issues than dictionary lookup vs array lookup. For what its worth, the server I work on receives *many* more hits than that, but I still wouldn't micro-optimise at the cost of readability without hard profiling evidence.

Comment: (Greg is absolutely right about new dictionaries, btw - it's a shame there isn't a ReadOnlyDictionary collection in the BCL.)

Comment: If you're asking questions like this, I'm hoping you're not working on a high traffic site.  That said, please, please, please, default to writing the most readable code, and if you need to change it later for performance reasons, it should be trivial, because it's already easy to read.

Comment: If you're binding it to a dropdownlist, that suggests you're depending on the ordering. However, a Dictionary does not guarantee any ordering when enumerating it. It may work now, but there's no guarantee it will in the future. That alone might be a good reason to switch.

Comment: Isn't this the case of premature optimization? For 12 values, how does it matter whether one uses array vs a dictionary, when it comes to performance?

Answer (score 8):

You should say to your boss: "I use a dictionary because it leads to more readable and maintainable code. If during testing we detect performance problems in the application, and profiling demonstrates that it is the fault of the dictionary, then I will try with an array."

Comment: Haha. Nice. In this case however an array would be just as readable IMO.

Comment: Actually I wanted to provide an answer than can be used whenever people says "this or that is more efficient" without actually knowing what they are speaking about.

Comment: yea, only if my boss cared about that.  All he cares about is the most performance which is fine, readability second.  Unfortunately, he doesn't see readablility and performance together most of the time which is why our codebase is a mess.

Comment: That's what I suspected as soon as I read "My boss says that an array is more efficient". :-)

Comment: "yea, only if my boss cared about that."  If your boss spends time on issues like this, he has too much time on his hands.

Answer (score 2):

The basic cycle of performance testing is as follows:

1. Define performance requirements
2. Measure actual performance
3. If actual performance is >= requirements, stop
4. Profile application and find bottleneck(s)
5. Try to fix bottlenecks
6. Go to 2

By "define performance requirements" I mean you need concrete things that can be quantitatively measured, for example:

> We require that the application can handle at least 100 concurrent users, with think times centred around the mean using normal distribution, each having a time to last byte (TTLB) of no more than 2 seconds, carrying out the following set of key business scenarios: 50% browsing products, 10% purchasing products, 20% doing some other thing, 20% doing yet another thing.

If you haven't done (1) then you cannot proceed to (2) so hang on until you've done that. If you've done (1) then you can follow the remainder of the steps, and the answer as to whether you need to optimise this code will drop out of that.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. if you need to put something with fixed, continuous numeral indexes - indeed, there is no point adding 1,2,3,4,5...etc because simple array will do it for you.

Your boss is right, you should change it to string[] array or [StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx).

Comment: Best argument in favor of using a simple array so far IMO. The small quirk is that the array index is zero-based and the month index is one-based. Not a huge difference but it will increase the chance for bugs and slightly decrease readability.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a Dictionary is only slightly less efficient than a List, if you're creating a business application, then it probably won't be the performance bottleneck.

However, semantically, a List would probably be just as good, unless you want to explicitly define the month indices (e.g. for clarity).

P.S. If you use a Dictionary, I'd rename the method to <strike>GetDictionaryOfMonths()</strike> GetMonths()

Comment: +1 for your keen observation that his method is named poorly :D

Comment: I'd name it GetMonths(), as the type of the object is obvious from, well, its type :)

Comment: Why should I have to put the type in as the name.  The name should imply intent.  The type is already part of the definition

Comment: Good point, I was thinking "How can he replace that word 'List' in  there?" instead of "How can he improve the method name?". Changed.

Comment: You're saying use a generic list instead?  Yea, I guess I could as a List is also index based

Answer (score 1):

Well, i just finished a benchMark to discover which is more fast way (List,array, dictionary) and make a 1000 times loop, and finally discover than dictionary is slightly (2%) more faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your boss is correct.  Since you are going to access it by the month number, you can have O(1) access to the value without the additional overhead of setting up the dictionary.

So I just read that you are populating a drop down list.  Instead of doing a look up to get the abbreviated name of the month, just put that as the drop down list value.

Comment: I think the performance is secondary in this example. A get on an Dictionary with 12 items is close enough to a get on an Array, provided you do not have any big loops which do repeatedly read the month. I guess the question here is more: is it really simpler?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an argument of trading memory for clock cycles. It's true that the Dictionary will have more extra overhead but if it's accessed frequently you should actually save clock cycles in the long run because you won't have to be looping through an array every time you want to look up a value.

But the main consideration here can be readability. Dictionary looksups are much easier to follow in code that array lookups. A little bit of overhead, very little with such a small collection, is well worth it IMHO.

Also for a bit of refactoring i would use `Dictionary<int, string>` for more obvious type safety and utilization. Doesn't make sense to use a string where an int is called for.

Answer (score 0):

Your boss is right but a switch is faster yet, so if you really want performance (only applicable if the above code is actually a bottleneck) use a switch instead. It Will be harder to read but it Will be faster